# VBA Find works when running from active sheet but not from the button on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the cell using the formula below but it errors out. The data is located on `ws1` sheet and I have the run macro button on the Engine sheet. If I run the macro from the module while I have `ws1` selected the macro runs without issue. If I run the macro using the button on the Engine sheet it errors out. I tried adding `ws1.actiavte` above this line of code but it does not fix the issue.

FYI C7=4/1/2022

```
Set myr = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engine").Range("C7").Value, after:=ws1.Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlNext)
```

Adding LookIn:=xlFormulas resolved the issue. The range.find of a date required LookIn:=xlFormulas in order to work it appears.

`Set myr = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engine").Range("C7").Value, after:=ws1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _     LookAt:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlNext)`

Comment: You should also specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters of `Find`.

Comment: Also [test if the Find succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589939/how-to-detect-whether-vba-excel-found-something).

Comment: I made this change and it still didnt work, additionally when i hover over myr it says nothing which i believe that the find did succeed


 `Set myr = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engine").Range("C7").Value, after:=ws1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas And xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlNext)`

Comment: `LookIn:=xlFormulas And xlValues` is not valid. Also looking up dates is tricky, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641402

Comment: Thanks BigBen, look in formulas worked and the link explains why. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding LookIn:=xlFormulas resolved the issue. The range.find of a date required LookIn:=xlFormulas in order to work it appears.

`Set myr = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engine").Range("C7").Value, after:=ws1.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _     LookAt:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlNext)`