# Range.Find(Function.Range)

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

```
Sub rollforward()

Dim ua As Worksheet: Set ua = Sheets("Unit Activity Adj Tab")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Assumptions")

ua.Range("G1:CX1").Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ws.Range("B1"),0)).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)

End Sub
```

This will not work!  I can't figure it out.  I keep getting a error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set

Comment: When using `Find`, *always* specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters, and *always* [test if the Find succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589939/how-to-detect-whether-vba-excel-found-something). Also `Find` can be tricky with dates.

Comment: I've even tried:
 ua.Range("G1:CX1").Find(ws.Range("B1")).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
But I get the same error

Comment: Now that I know you're working with formulae in that range, as opposed to actual dates... See [Range.Find on a Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641402/3233363)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to break down the code to be a little more manageable:

```
Sub rollforward()
    Dim ua As Worksheet: Set ua = Sheets("Unit Activity Adj Tab")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Assumptions")
    Dim findTerm As String:  findTerm = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(ws.Range("B1").Value,0), "mm/dd/yyyy") 'UPDATE FOR YOUR FORMAT
    Dim findRange As Range:  Set findRange = ua.Range("G1:CX1").Find(findTerm) 'Add looks ins, etc.
    If findRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    findRange.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
End Sub
```

Couple things I've done:

- Separated out the term you're finding.  You may need some validation for the input on this to ensure `EoMonth()` can do its job.
- Added `.Value` to your search value to ensure you're using only the value.
- Added an error check for your `Find()` in case something isn't found.
- Added an action on the found range after the error check.

Now, a couple of things... you may need to format your output...  `Debug.Print Application.EoMonth(Now(), 0)` outputs `44804`.  You may have trouble finding that, and may need to verify that your find range is not in strings, etc.

---

Edit1:  Added `format()` to `findTerm` which should allow the appropriate finding.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, even when I remove the function and just replace it with findTerm = ws.Range("B1").  The range("G1:CX1") are EOMONTH functions.  Is it possible that even though the date is being produced, since there's functions in the cells it's having trouble finding the date?

Comment: If I replace the ws.Range("B1") with "7/31/2022" then it works but I can't get the range to work.  I'm also trying the range with .Value.

Comment: @B-Rye I was just updated my code, which now includes `format()` in the `findTerm`... sorry, was working on that in Excel, because the formatting is very important as it can't find the generic date.

Comment: @B-Rye Just posted a link to Ron's loop for this, as it I believe your question has already been answered.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!  I was missing for Format()