# Using Command Button to Search Row for Word - Named Range

Tags: excel, vba

This macro uses the caption written on a command button to search row 2 for a value that is the same as the caption. It works well, but I am trying to make it a little cleaner by using the Application.GoTo Scroll method instead of MyRange.Select

However, I can't seem to get the named range "MyRange" to work in this method. Any recommendations on how to rewrite the code?

```
Sub Navigator_Sections()

Dim ButtonName As String
Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
ButtonName = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption

    lnRow = 2
    lnCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=ButtonName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    
    Set MyRange = Cells(lnRow, lnCol)
    Set MyRange = MyRange.Offset(0, -2)
    
    Application.Goto Reference:=ActiveSheet.Range("MyRange"), Scroll:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.GoTo MyRange, True`?

Comment: Also, it's always safest to [Test if the Find succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589939/how-to-detect-whether-vba-excel-found-something) first.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be simple.     Application.Goto MyRange, Scroll:=True

Answer (score 0):

Application.Goto MyRange, Scroll:=True

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Always test if the `Find` succeeded.
2. `MyRange` is a `Range` object already. No quotes, no reference to `ActiveSheet`.

```
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Rows(lnRow).Find( _
                  What:=ButtonName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False)

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
   If myRange.Column > 2 Then
       Application.GoTo MyRange.Offset(,-2), True
   End If
End If
```