# Find Result is Inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have this Excel VBA code.

```vb
Sub setEVAFieldValue(pattern As String, fval As Variant)
    Dim lrange As Range
    Dim lrange2 As Range
    Dim lrange3 As Range
    Dim rowpos As Integer
    Dim colpos As Integer

    Set lrange = Worksheets("EVA").Cells.Find(pattern)
    If (lrange.Row > 0) Then
        rowpos = lrange.Row
        colpos = lrange.Column
        Worksheets("EVA").Cells(rowpos, colpos + 2).value = fval
    End If
End Sub
```

This normally finds the cell with the pattern and adds the values to the adjacent cell.

But when another piece of code in the worksheet does some calculations and shows a form with these calculations, the find does not work any more. It returns nothing for the range, even if I see the cell in the worksheet with the pattern.

Example of a pattern: "Beta"

The call used: `Call setEVAFieldValue("Beta", betaValue)`

The value in the cell: "5)  Beta"
The value in the cell is without the double quotes

Comment: When using `Find`, you should always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters. You should also [test if the Find succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589939/how-to-detect-whether-vba-excel-found-something).

Comment: Btw, the `.Row` of a `Range` object will always be `>0` (minimum is 1).

Comment: tried with all parameter and still returns a nothing object

Comment: Hmm. Can you add an example of the pattern you're using, and the cell value that matches the pattern? Does your other code perform a `Find` or maybe a `Replace`?

Comment: a find and sure i will ad a example

Comment: Can you also add the other `Find`? From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find): The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

Comment: thank you it seems to have worked, i added the LookAt:=xlPart and seems to have fix it. did no know the find parameters would be overwriten

Comment: @BIgBen it would be cool if you at that last comment as answer so you can get the recognition for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) docs:

> The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

Said otherwise, when using `Find`, always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters (and `SearchOrder` and `MatchByte` if they are relevant to the find you're performing).