# Find an Excel Cell Reference from within a Word Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am in the process of automating a booking process using Word VBA.
I have everything working wonderfully.

As an extra function I would like to open an Excel file, locate an invoice number, get the cell reference and then add todays date 4 cells to the right.
I have got as far as finding the invoice number but I'm stuck as to how to proceed as the offset statement causes a compile error.

Any suggestions welcome.

My test code is below.

```
    Sub FindString()
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim xlBook As Object
        Dim InvTrkFileName As String
        Dim InvTrkFilePath As String
        Dim VFInvNos As String
        Dim c As Range
        Dim firstAddress As String
        Dim BaseFilePath As String
    
        BaseFilePath = "School%20Bookings/"
        InvTrkFilePath = "Invoicing%20Process/Invoice%20Tracker%2020"
    
        VFInvNos = "CCH24016"
        'Get Invoice Number from Tracker and insert Visit Date in Tracker
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        If Err Then
          Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        InvTrkFileName = BaseFilePath & InvTrkFilePath & "24.xlsx"
        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=InvTrkFileName)
        With xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            Set c = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=VFInvNos)
            Set c = c.Offset(0, 4)
            Set c.Value = Today
        End With
        
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
    
    End Sub
```

I have tried multiple solutions having searched the web.

Comment: `Dim c As Object`. Currently it's declared as a Word `Range`, but you're attempting to assign an Excel `Range` to it.

Comment: `Dim c As Excel.Range `

Comment: @JonathanWillcock OP is late-binding here though (`Dim xlApp As Object`, `Dim xlBook As Object`) , so `As Object` is appropriate, not the early-bound `Excel.Range`.

Comment: @BigBen True, I would much rather use Excel.Application and Excel.Workbook as well.  I see no good reason for late-binding here.

Comment: @BigBen Actually I was working on the basis that the OP knew that Range.Offset returns another Range and was therefore deliberately trying to use early-binding in his definition of c.  I was merely pointing out to him that if he wants to declare c as a Range, he needs to be specific that it is an Excel Range.  I usually try to push an OP towards a solution that is as close as possible to what they originally had (on the basis that it will be easier for them to understand).  On this basis `Excel.Range` as opposed to `Object` seemed closer to the OP's original intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim c As Range` is implicitly `Dim c As Word.Range`, but a Word [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) object is quite different from an Excel [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object.

The late-bound fix:

```
Dim c As Object
Const xlValues As Long = -4163
Const xlWhole As Long = 1
```

which is consistent with the late-binding you already have.

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
```

Another option is to early-bind, which requires that you check the Microsoft Excel ##.0 Object Library under Tools > References.

[image]

Once you have that reference:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
...
Dim c As Excel.Range
```

Note that your current code assumes that the `Find` actually found something. Instead you should [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589939/how-to-detect-whether-vba-excel-found-something) whether the `Find` succeeded, and you should (at a minimum) also specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters:

```
Set c = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=VFInvNos, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    c.Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
End If
```

Also your `With xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and `End With` aren't actually being used and can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer to complement BigBen's, so I will not cover the same points. My starting point, however, is the point that you were stuck over: namely, why did your code not compile?  I take it that you were puzzled because you knew that an (Excel) Range has an Offset method, which returns another (Excel) Range.

The short answer is that your definition `Dim c As Range` is interpreted by the compiler as being a Word Range, not an Excel one.  A Word Range does not have an Offset method and therefore the compiler complains and raises a compilation error.

So how to get rid of the error?

There are basically two approaches: one as suggested by BigBen (which I shall hereafter refer to as the late-binding approach), and the other by me (the early-binding approach).

Using the late-binding approach, you change your declaration to `Dim c As Object`.  Suddenly (miraculously you might think) your method compiles.  Why is this? How does the compiler know that the `Object` c contains a method called `Offset`, whereas when declaring as Range, it did not?  In point of fact, it doesn't know.  An `Object` can be anything, and the compiler therefore has no way of knowing whether the `Object` that is created at run-time has this particular method or not.  In practice the compiler is trusting you, the programmer.  It has no way of knowing whether the `Object` has this method, but it is presuming that you know what you are doing and that at run-time the `Object` will indeed have this method. It therefore raises no objections at compile-time, but you incur the risk of a run-time error, if, for any reason, the `Object` created does not have this method.

The alternative is to use early-binding (and as BigBen rightfully points out), if you use early-binding, you should be consistent and use it throughout.  Under early-binding, you explicitly tell the compiler exactly what type of `Object` you want: in this case an `Excel.Range`.  The compiler can then look up the referenced library, check that an (Excel) Range does indeed contain an Offset method and will accordingly successfully compile.

So which should you use: late-binding or early-binding. I recommend using early-binding, whenever possible.  In this case it is certainly possible, because you the programmer know that you are creating an Excel Application, opening an Excel Workbook and accessing an Excel Range, so there is nothing to be gained from not being specific about it.

On the contrary, there is much to be gained from this approach.  If you use the late-binding approach and inadvertently misspell   Offset as Ofset, your code will compile(!), and you will only notice the error at run-time.  With early-binding, on the other hand, you get a compile-time error.  There are other advantages too, but this one alone is to my mind sufficient reason to go with early-binding: the possibility for error is massively reduced at runtime.

When then should you use late-binding?  There are times when you want to write generalised code.  The various Office Object Models are in many cases very similar: there are same named classes with same named methods, taking same types of parameters.  You might therefore want to write some code that takes either a string parameter (e.g. "Excel.Application" or "Word.Application") and then performs exactly the same tasks on the Application that gets created from this string or an Object parameter, which you the programmer know, will either be an Excel Application or a Word Application.  Using late-binding, you do not need to write similar code to handle an Excel Application, a Word Application, a PowerPoint Application and so on.  Generalised code saves time and is easier to maintain.

IMHO though this is not a case where you need such generalised code.  You are writing code to open a specific Excel Workbook to update a specific cell.  This is in no way a generalised case, so use specific code: use early-binding.

Comment: @Chris The way this site works, is by creating a pool of good questions and good answers. If an answer has helped you, then you have two possibilities (not exclusive), you can accept and/or upvote. To accept you need to click on the "greyed out" checkbox. Don't worry, this is a design flaw of SO, it looks as though you can't click,  but you can! The other possibility is to upvote an answer. Why do either? There is no requirement at all. This is very important, it is up to you what you do. However accepting or upvoting  helps other users find good solutions for the same problem.

Comment: Where does one find the checkbox?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for a full explanation.